# Length of a quotient in Hartshorne, IV, Ex. 1.8.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry, IV, Ex. 1.8., he considers $\text{length}(\tilde{\mathscr{O}_P}/\mathscr{O}_P)$, where $\mathscr{O}_P$ is the local ring of $X$ (considered also as the skyscraper sheaf) at the closed point $P\in X$ for an integral separated finite-type $k$-scheme $X$ of dimension 1. Here, $\tilde{\mathscr{O}_P}$ is just the integral closure.

I can see how we can look at the length of the $\mathscr{O}_P$-module $\tilde{\mathscr{O}_P}$ but I don't think that the length of the quotient makes sense. Is this (the former) what he means? Also, since this is a finite extension of $k$-algebras, is this the same as the size of longest chain of $k$-vector subspaces $\mathscr{O}_P\subset\cdots\subset V\subset\cdots\subset \tilde{\mathscr{O}_P}$?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this (the former) what he means?

I don't think so. There is an inclusion $\mathcal{O}_P \subset \widetilde{\mathcal{O}}_P$, which gives $\widetilde{\mathcal{O}}_P$ the structure of an $\mathcal{O}_P$-module. Thus $\widetilde{\mathcal{O}}_P / \mathcal{O}_P$ also is an $\mathcal{O}_P$-module, and thus has a length.

You are right, that the length of $\widetilde{\mathcal{O}}_P / \mathcal{O}_P$ is the same its $k$-vector space dimension. This is because there is a homomorphism $\mathcal{O}_P \to \mathcal{O}_P / \mathfrak{m}_P = k$. Thus any chain of $k$-vector spaces in $\widetilde{\mathcal{O}}_P / \mathcal{O}_P$ gives a chain of $\mathcal{O}_P$-modules. Because the homomorphism is surective, every chain of $\mathcal{O}_P$-modules also is a chain of $k$-vector spaces.